# How to add button to plotly chart to toggle multi traces?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

how to add button like this below to toggle data from all traces on the scatter?
[image: toggle buttons]

Thanks,
Paulina

Comment: Just to confirm, did you know that you can hide the graph by clicking on the legend?

Comment: @r-beginners Yes, I know. Is this related?

Comment: I mistakenly thought the function of that button was to show or hide the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hover text data comparison button on the menu bar does not appear to be visible at all times. I do not know why. Adding the following code will make it appear.
This tips was confirmed from [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/3274).

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Create random data with numpy
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

N = 100
random_x = np.linspace(0, 1, N)
random_y0 = np.random.randn(N) + 5
random_y1 = np.random.randn(N)
random_y2 = np.random.randn(N) - 5

fig = go.Figure()

# Add traces
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=random_x, y=random_y0,
                    mode='markers',
                    name='markers'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=random_x, y=random_y1,
                    mode='lines+markers',
                    name='lines+markers'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=random_x, y=random_y2,
                    mode='lines',
                    name='lines'))


fig.update_layout(modebar_add=[
    "v1hovermode",
    "toggleSpikelines",
])

fig
```

[image]